# How many elements of order $7$ are there in a group of order $28$ without Sylow's theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof, sylow-theory

How many elements of order $7$ are there in a group of order $28~?$

---

I need to prove this result without using the Sylow's Theorem.By Sylow's Theorem it has only one subgroup and the answer becomes $~6$. But in the book the problem is in the Cauchy's Theorem chapter and I want to prove it by this only.Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By Cauchy's theorem the group, say $G$, has an element $g$ of order $7$. To the contrary, assume $G$ has an element $h$ of order $7$ not contained in $\langle g \rangle$. Then, 
$\langle g \rangle \langle h\rangle$ has size $49 > 28$ (why?), a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

the number of subgroups is 6, by using Euler's function for phi(7)=7*(1-1/7)=6. One more thing, order of the group must be divisible to 7,  else your condition will not well defined. So order of group is 28 (28/7).

Comment: Welcome to MSE @MajidkhanAzizov. It is often more useful if you use MathJax and help increase the readability of your posts.